# grab full url from ESP8266WebServer

Tags: webserver, uri, esp8266, esp8266wifi

This question must be a duplicate, but I cannot find the answer.
Using the `ESP8266WebServer` library, there is an `uri()` method to grab the uri. So in the example: `http://example.com/index`, it will grab `/index`, but I would also like to get the `example.com`. IS there a method for that?

Comment: you don't know the hostname of your esp8266? the name was resolved by the client and the client sent the uri to the IP address of your esp8266

Comment: well, in the case of `server.onNotFound` I would like to know what the station was looking for. I can only see the uri. Isn't there a way to determine which full url was sent to the esp?

Comment: you can read the Host header. the http(s)://host:port part is not sent to server. the client uses the hostname to resolve the IP address and then the client makes a connection to the IP address on the specified port

Comment: How do i read the Host header? Since everything is served by the esp, including dns, should I be able to get the  http(s)://host:port part?

Comment: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer#getting-information-about-request-headers

Comment: @Juraj indeed `Serial.println(server.hostHeader());` solves my problem. You can answer the question if you want the badges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `http(s)://host:port` part is not sent to server. The client uses the hostname to resolve the IP address and then the client makes a connection to the IP address on the specified port.

But HTTP 1.1 has a mandatory Host header in requests to a HTTP server.

The ESP8266 Arduino ESP8266WebServer library makes the current request's headers accessible on the ESP8266WebServer instance. To get the Host header there is a `hostHeader()` method.

Example:

```
void handleRoot() {
  Serial.print("The Host: header value: ");
  Serial.println(server.hostHeader());
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "hello from esp8266!\r\n");
}
```

Documentation for the ESP8266WebServer is [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer#esp8266-web-server).